# JAVA loop issue

Tags: java, mpi

Hi all i am having issues with a loop for my code, what i am trying to do is run a section of code 20 times, keep track of the time taken, and then work out the average by dividing by 20

here is the code at the moment that does not work :

```
edit
```

it gives me the following error :

```
PJ Express (0.35) is started in the cluster configuration
Starting process <0> on <Tornado>
Starting process <1> on <Predator>
mpi.MPIException: Error in SimplePacker : count <1> is less than length <2>
        at mpi.SimplePackerChar.unpack(SimplePackerChar.java:105)
        at mpi.Comm.recv(Comm.java:1305)
        at mpi.Comm.Recv(Comm.java:1255)
        at PingPongVariousLengths.main(PingPongVariousLengths.java:29)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at runtime.daemon.Wrapper.execute(Wrapper.java:165)
        at runtime.daemon.Wrapper.main(Wrapper.java:180)
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at runtime.daemon.Wrapper.execute(Wrapper.java:165)
        at runtime.daemon.Wrapper.main(Wrapper.java:180)
Caused by: mpi.MPIException: mpi.MPIException: mpi.MPIException: Error in Simple
Packer : count <1> is less than length <2>
        at mpi.Comm.Recv(Comm.java:1259)
        at PingPongVariousLengths.main(PingPongVariousLengths.java:29)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: mpi.MPIException: mpi.MPIException: Error in SimplePacker : count <1>
 is less than length <2>
        at mpi.Comm.recv(Comm.java:1317)
        at mpi.Comm.Recv(Comm.java:1255)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: mpi.MPIException: Error in SimplePacker : count <1> is less than leng
th <2>
        at mpi.SimplePackerChar.unpack(SimplePackerChar.java:105)
        at mpi.Comm.recv(Comm.java:1305)
        ... 8 more
```

however before the loop was added, i had this code and it was working fine :

edit

what is causing the loop in the program to give the error message, and how can i solve this issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

the error is in SimplePacker and a MPIException is thrown.
Can you provide some coder of your SimplePacker, which gets invoked in MPI.Rec()- method?

Comment: you asked the same question yesterday!

Comment: Yes, but did not find an answer, it is really confusing me

Comment: So why is it then that the other question has an accepted answer? Come on!

Comment: The acceped answer was for the loop question, it was after that i have had this issue, and thank you, what is done wrong, as before the loop was added, the code was working perfectly fine, as shown above